# How do microbiologists decide whether two morphotypes on the same plate belong to the same strain?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, bacteriology, morphology

### Background

**Colony**: A colony, in microbiology, is a visible cluster or mass of microorganisms (such as bacteria or fungi) that has grown and multiplied on a solid agar medium. Each colony represents a population of genetically identical microbial cells that originated from a single cell or a small group of cells. Colony formation is an essential step in the isolation and identification of microorganisms.

**Colony morphology** refers to the visible characteristics of a bacterial or fungal colony when grown on a solid agar medium. It includes features such as size, shape, color, texture, and edge appearance. Each type of microorganism may exhibit distinct colony morphologies, aiding in their identification and classification.

"It should be noted that when a microbiologist examines an agar plate and determines that mixed bacterial
types are present, it is actually mixed bacterial colonial types (morphotypes) that are being observed. These
visually distinctive colonies often represent different species (or even genera), but they may also represent
phenotypic variants of a single genotypic organism."

> Koneman's Color Atlas and Textbook of Diagnostic Microbiology. 7th.
> Wolters Kluwer; 2017

### Question

In diagnostic microbiology and in order to save time, how do microbiologists decide whether two morphotypes on the same plate belong to the same strain?

I'm not talking about great differences in morphologies as Lactose fermenters vs Non-Lactose fermenters on MacConkey agar, but ones like these: The center in Type A is purple while the center in Type B is pink.
[image: Pure culture of Acinetobacter on MacConkey agar plate]

Pure culture of *Acinetobacter* on MacConkey agar plate

Comment: They don't look any different to me from your photo. Perhaps a closer photo might help. All I see is some difference in thickness (depth?) of the colony perhaps, so one appears lighter colour than the other.

Comment: I will try to find a more clear example and I will add more essential quoted text to the background section about "Phenotypic Variants of Bacterial Colonies"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that when a microbiologist looks at a plate, they are looking to observe a particular something, which depends on exactly what they are doing, and they will have some idea of the range of morphotypes expected for those species and/or strains.

They also aren't doing this in isolation - they will use tests to further confirm what they see, often starting with simple tests like [Gram staining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_stain) and going on to other biochemical tests, genetic tests (sequencing possibly or PCR), or even [MALDI-ToF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix-assisted_laser_desorption/ionization#Microbiology).

Experience also plays a part - if this is something being done routinely, say in a clinical lab, then the investigator know what species to expect, and which ones are things to further investigate for that particular sample type. This means they will have some idea (it may not be formal knowledge, as in taught, just experience) of the range of potential morphotypes for a particular species and be able to use that information to assess a plate quickly and accurately. Exact identification of a strain and/or species is often impossible without further testing  (e.g. you can't normally tell the difference between antibiotic resistant and non-antibiotic resistant strains without susceptibility testing, or even the difference between various *Streptococcus* species without testing), though pathogenic factors such as bacterial capsules in some strains of a species (e.g. [capsules in *E. coli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escherichia_coli#Role_in_disease)*), might be obvious from colony morphology immediately.

In the case of a pure strain streaked on a plate, as in your photo, changes in colony morphology might or might not indicate genetic changes reflected by phenotypic changes. An example might be loss of flagellae, means the bacteria are no longer motile, so the colony is less spread-out than ones with flagellae. Pigementation changes might also indicate a phenotypic and/or genetic change - perhaps processing a metabolite by a different pathway or able to do it only under certain conditions - no genetic change, just a phenotypic.

Comment: "There may also be variation in morphologies of colonies of the same
strain. Hence categorization if isolates based on specific colony
characteristics should be broad and based on several aspects of
morphology rather than on only one or two characteristics. "


What could be the variable characteristics that one should not always rely on? From my example color seems to be one.

Comment: @FreezingSoul Categorization based on colony characteristics is necessarily broad. It is usually the very first step in ID, followed by more specific tests to discriminate between species or groups of types.  If you were using a dichotomous key, it would be one of the first steps in ID it's that fundamental.

Comment: @FreezingSoul There's no one variable because it changes with each organism. An equivalent (at the risk of sounding racist; no racist intention here) might be comparing races of people - Asiatic peoples tend to have straight dark hair, so it's not a good characteristic to separate them internally into regions, but is useful to separate them from Caucasians and Africans (=genus from colony in bacteria), but in Caucasians hair might be useful for separating out groups internally (Germanic = blonde; Hispanic = dark, curly; Hibernian = red, equivalent to species within a genus for the bacteria)

Comment: Are you saying that one should learn about the possible colony variation for the potential species that could be obtained in a given case?

Comment: @FreezingSoul Yes. There's no "one answer fits all" here.

Comment: But in diagnostic microbiology, especially when the number of possible pathogens in a situation is high, there must be some terms that can be generally applied. I'm starting to become convinced that color and size are two characteristics that one should be skeptical of when interpreting. Do you have any personal experience or text that could go with this?

Comment: @FreezingSoul not really, if you know the sample type, then there are well known pathogens that are the prime candidates. E.g. for a throat sample, think streptococci, not *E. coli*, so looking for small creamy entire colonies +/- hemolytic on blood, then narrow down using specific tests. Try Mim's diagnostic microbiology.

Comment: Yeah, maybe i need to use this approach.

Comment: @FreezingSoul 100+ years (since the late 1800's) of diagnostic microbiology could have given you a hint that the processes and easiest ways have already been worked out. As I said in the answer, none of this is done in isolation, you have other information about the sample that can help to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Maybe, I might be wrong at some obvious cases as the throat sample. But what about the number of candidates that different types of nosocomial infections feature? Each type of infection (UTI, pneumonia....) can be caused by a good number and to make matters worse, causative bacterial species can overlap between different infection types.

Comment: @FreezingSoul You are overthinking it. In the medical training axiom: "If you hear hooves, think *those are horses* not *those are zebras*". Yes, some pathogens might be missed for rare cases, but that's where further investigation (repeat samples etc.) comes in. Overlap can be a problem, but the problem species is usually the most abundant species in the sample. Experience and training will tell you when this isn't the case!

Comment: Yeah, that's me honestly. I'm putting my hand in the jar and trying to get everything out, then end up getting nothing. Thanks for your time and help.